# OpenERP visible field to certain user groups

Tags: odoo

I am working on xml in openerp. I am creating access right for an specific user. I want to know if is possible to add more than one group in the groups tag adding a comma, semicolon or some char?

I've tried this but it is not working:

```
groups="x_stock_picking.confirm_transfer, stock.group_stock_user"
```

is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate them with coma without any spaces.

```
groups="x_stock_picking.confirm_transfer,stock.group_stock_user"
```